# How do I bypass a call to super method in test

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I have a basic structure like this

```
class Automobile
  def some_method
    # this code sets up structure for child classes... I want to test this
  end
end

class Car < Automobile
  def some_method
    super
    # code specific to Car... it's tested elsewhere so I don't want to test this now
  end
end

class CompactCar < Car
  def some_method
    super
    # code specific to CompactCar... I want to test this
  end
end
```

What is the recommended way to test `CompactCar` and `Automobile` without running the code from `Car`?  `Automobile#some_method` provides the structure that is required by child classes, so I want to always test that, but `Car's` functionality is tested elsewhere and I don't want to duplicate efforts.

One solution is to use `class_eval` to overwrite `Car#some_method`, but this isn't ideal because the overwritten method stays in place for the duration of my testing (unless I re-load the original library file with setup/teardown methods... kind of an ugly solution).  Also, simply stubbing the call to `Car#some_method` does not seem to work.

Is there a cleaner/more generally accepted way of doing this?

Comment: Depends on what is in the method but you could test what is left in `some_method` rather than testing `some_method` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the specific code into a separate method. You don't appear to be using anything from super. Unless you are?

```
class CompactCar < Car
  def some_method
    super
    compact_car_specific_code
  end

  # Test this method in isolation.
  def compact_car_specific_code
    # code specific to CompactCar... I want to test this
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, super is definitely being used in the real world.  Essentially, `Automobile` sets up the data structure, and `Car` and `CompactCar` do the work on that structure.  I originally didn't want to pull out the code specific for `CompactCar`, but I just may have to do that.

Comment: In that case, I'd mock/stub to simulate the effect of super rather than depend upon it. Then test super separately.